# Converting a pandas DataFrame results in an empty Spark DataFrame yet no errors or warnings raised

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have several years of `pyspark` experience: but mostly it includes converting `Spark` `DataFrame`'s to `pandas`.  When trying the inverse it seems to be less predictable.

Given a modest `pandas` dataframe *pdf* here is the simplest code converting it to `spark`.  Note I had been providing a full `StructType` / *schema* but that did not work so I am making it as simple as possible by converting all fields to `str` first:

```
sdf =  spark.createDataFrame(pdf.astype(str))
```

Here was the basics of the code that was also not working - using fully defined column types:

```
sdf =  spark.createDataFrame(pdf,StructType(scols))
```

In both cases the `sdf` spark dataframe is created - but it is *empty*.  We can see both the original pandas `pdf` and spark `sdf` in the `pycharm` debugger: the former has 11 rows while the latter is empty:

[image]

What is  going on ? I mean at least an *error* should be thrown providing some hint on why `spark` were unhappy.

Comment: Sorry to say that I have no idea about your problem but every time I convert between `pdf` to `sdf` or `sdf` to `pdf` it seems ok to me, even with `astype(str)` or not.